# How many i reuse this same function multiple times on a page

Tags: javascript, arguments

I want to make this media player timer appear multiple times on the same page, with different variables settings, without reusing the same code.

This is my current timer looks like this...

```
<div id="countdown_1" class="count"></div>
<script>
var releaseDate = new Date('06/30/2020 10:30 PM UTC+1');
var expiryDate = new Date('07/20/2020 12:00 PM UTC+1');
var media = "<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/BBYzqI-fnHE\" frameborder=\"0\" allow=\"accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture\" allowfullscreen><\/iframe>";

</script>
```

In timer.js

```
(function () {


    var _second = 1000;
    var _minute = _second * 60;
    var _hour = _minute * 60;
    var _day = _hour * 24;
    var timer;

    function showRemaining() {
        var now = new Date();
        var distance = releaseDate - now;
        var gone = expiryDate - now;
                if (distance < 0 && gone > 0) {

            clearInterval(timer);
            document.getElementById('countdown_1').innerHTML = media;

            return;
        }
                if (gone < 0) {

            clearInterval(timer);
            document.getElementById('countdown_1').innerHTML = 'This video has now expired';

            return;
        }        
        
        var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

        document.getElementById('countdown_1').innerHTML ='Media player will appear automatically in:<br><br>';
        document.getElementById('countdown_1').innerHTML += days + ' Days ';
        document.getElementById('countdown_1').innerHTML += hours + ' Hours ';
        document.getElementById('countdown_1').innerHTML += minutes + ' Minutes ';
        document.getElementById('countdown_1').innerHTML += seconds + ' Seconds';
    }

    timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);

}());
```

Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/agileapricot/zft6cohu/5

I believe I need to make the timer a named function with arguments?

```
(function MediaTimer(releaseDate,expiryDate,media) {

    var _second = 1000;
    var _minute = _second * 60;
    var _hour = _minute * 60;
    var _day = _hour * 24;
    var timer;
```

But then how can I call it on the page with the variable types I need for the releaseDate, expiryDate and media code?

```
    MediaTimer();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track with that. What i would do is name my timers with Ids that would be easy to concatenate like this :

```
<div id="countdown_1" class="count"></div>
<div id="countdown_2" class="count"></div>
<div id="countdown_3" class="count"></div>
```

then i would create an Array with all the Dates i need :

```
var dates = [{releaseDate: new Date(bla), expiracyDate : new Date(bla)},
{releaseDate: new Date(bla), expiracyDate : new Date(bla)},
{releaseDate: new Date(bla), expiracyDate : new Date(bla)}]
```

And then simply call the function   `MediaTimer()` within a for loop and passing it an index:

```
for(var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++){
    MediaTimer(i);
}
```

And finally, the mediaTimer function would look like this :

```
function MediaTimer(index) {

    var _second = 1000;
    var _minute = _second * 60;
    var _hour = _minute * 60;
    var _day = _hour * 24;
    var timer;

    function showRemaining() {
        var elementId = 'countdown_' + (index+1);
        var now = new Date();
        var distance = dates[index].releaseDate - now;
        var gone = dates[index].expiracyDate - now;
                if (distance < 0 && gone > 0) {

            clearInterval(timer);
            document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML = media;
                                              //not sure what is media

            return;
        }
                if (gone < 0) {

            clearInterval(timer);
            document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML = 'This video has now expired';

            return;
        }        
        
        var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

        document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML ='Media player will appear automatically in:<br><br>';
        document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML += days + ' Days ';
        document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML += hours + ' Hours ';
        document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML += minutes + ' Minutes ';
        document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML += seconds + ' Seconds';
    }

    timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);

};
```

This would allow you to have multiple timers with different dates, using the same function